# trouble with drawing graph

Tags: graphs

So, I am using `\usepackage{tikz-cd}` and here is my code which causes arrows during compilation.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzcd}
        X \arrow{r}{f} \arrow{d}{\alpha} & Y \arrow{r}{g} \arrow{d}{\beta} & Z \arrow{r}{h} & X[1] \arrow{d}{\alpha[1]}\\
        X_1 \arrow{r}{f_1} & Y_1 \arrow{r}{g_1} & Z_1 \arrow{r}{h_1} & X_1[1] 
    \end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

This seems alright to me. The point (in context) is that `$Z \to Z_1$` is not in this graph, so don't add `\arrow{d}` in the first row after `\arrow{r}{h}`.

Comment: Please make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: If I build a minimal document from your fragment, it compiles without problem and produces the output that one would expect. So please follow the advice of samcarter and provide a complete document that illustrates the problem.

Comment: You don't have an arrow from Z to Z_1 because you didn't write it. Just add `\arrow{d}{\gamma}` (or whatever label you want).

Comment: Yeah, the problem was later in the code, I used arrow without endpoint... Thanks anyway!!